# Visual Studio Code's intellisense doesn't recognize Arduino port managing

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, intellisense

I'm trying to use VScode for Arduino Uno early development. I'd like to use intellisense but in the "Problems tab" it shows me errors:

```
identifier "DDRD" is undefined
identifier "PIND" is undefined
identifier "PORTD" is undefined
identifier "PORTD" is undefined
```

I can compile and upload the code flawlessly and it works.

I read everywhere that the solution to this is adding at the very top of the code the macro definition of the microcontroller, but it seems that this doesn't work for me only.

This is my code

```
#define __AVR_ATmega328P__
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
    int switchState = 0;

    DDRD &= ~(1 << 2);
    DDRD |= 1 << 3;
    DDRD |= 1 << 4;
    DDRD |= 1 << 5;

    for (;;) {
        switchState = 0x01 & (PIND >> 2);

        if (!switchState) {
            PORTD |= 1 << 3;
            PORTD &= ~(1 << 4);
            PORTD &= ~(1 << 5);
        } else {
            PORTD &= ~(1 << 3);
            PORTD &= ~(1 << 4);
            PORTD |= 1 << 5;
            _delay_ms(250);
            PORTD |= 1 << 4;
            PORTD &= ~(1 << 5);
            _delay_ms(250);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I right-click a DDRD underlined macro and select "Go to definition" it brings me to the DDRD macro definition in io76c711.h, while I expect been redirected in iom328p.h, because io.h contains

```
#elif defined (__AVR_ATmega328P__)
#  include <avr/iom328p.h>
```

It seems that **AVR_AT76C711** is defined somewhere else but I can't wonder where.

Do you have any suggestion? I also post my c_cpp_properties.json if there is something wrong in the one generated by the VScode Arduino extension

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools\\**",
                "D:\\Arduino\\libraries\\**",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\libraries\\**",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\**",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\**"
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\Arduino.h"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "USBCON"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Why do you need Intellisense to see how DDRD is defined?

Comment: Thx 4 the answer. I don't want to see how it's defined, I just want want to write the code without it's shown as an error, I reported the definition I fount just for helping you understanding the reason.

Comment: #define __AVR_ATmega328P__ is found somewhere?/somehow? and arduino.h is included as part of the build which in tern refers to <avr/io.h> which in turn digs deep to find PORTD et al, so I don't think you need either of those.  I'm having the same issue with intellisense  (I don't like to see warning or errors in code) and I suspect that it doesn't know about these at the time of a verify.

Comment: Also, how do you know that  AVR_AT76C711  results in  __AVR_ATmega328P__?  It looks to me as if you have set the board/cpu or whatever in an external configuration somewhere to AVR_AT76C711 which is why it is finding io76c711.h.

Answer (score 6):

Add `"__AVR_ATmega328P__"` to the define section of your c_cpp_properties.json file as follows:

```
"defines": [
    "__AVR_ATmega328P__",
```

Then it will be able to find the correct AVR IO include file.

In your case, AVR_AT76C711 was just one possibility for the definition, but it likely wasn't actually defined in your project.

Note: the define will automatically be removed the next time that the IntelliSense Configuration is rebuilt (e.g.: Verify or Upload). This issue is currently tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/1279).

Comment: If you don't care about portability at all, you could just include the io header directly. `#include <avr/iom328p.h>`, to do this you must remove the `#include <avr/io.h>` if you have it.

Comment: That "defines" fixes the issue temporarily. But, when I verify the code, the "defines" section just ignores all the modifications I've made and goes back to the previous state. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @ShihaoXu Yeah, you are correct. See the paragraph in the answer labeled "Note:". If you follow the issue link, a workaround is presented that disables the "intelliSenseGen", which may or may not help you. Otherwise, Daniel Abdelsamed's suggestion is good too.

Comment: @gunderbolt Thanks for the reply. I do figure out another workaround: 
1. in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file, add a new section/profile called whatever you like (e.g., "Arduino Uno") and 
2. copy all the existing configurations to this newly created record. 
3. Then, add the `__AVR_ATmega328P__` into the "defines" section. 
4. Change C/C++ configuration to "Arudino Uno". Done.
Every time you verify/upload the code, the default profile "Arduino" will be reset, but this "Arduino Uno" profile stays the same.

Comment: @ShihaoXu Nice! I'll have to try that next time I work on my Arduino project!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the header files with register definitions/initializations such as <avr/iom328p.h> are only included at compile-time by the compiler. As a result, intellisense has no clue about those definitions while error-checking your code. By manually defining which board you use or by setting a compiler argument (which would normally be set at compile-time), you can get intellisense to recognize the necessary header files.

Adding the flag "-mmcu=atmega328" to my Arduino configuration's compilerArgs (within c_cpp_properties.json) resolved this intellisense issue. Obviously change the atmega chip number as needed.

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Arduino",
            "compilerPath":
                "path\\to\\your\\compiler",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-mmcu=atmega328"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "paths\\to\\include"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

If this change keeps getting cleared, it will be necessary to disable the auto-generation of the c_cpp_properties.json file. This setting ID is : *arduino.disableIntelliSenseAutoGen*